# How to pre-populate dropdown menu using existing database

Tags: angular, select, angular-material

I have an existing database I am able to pull from and populate my dropdown menu with using item.schoolName. When I access this "candidate form" it is specific to the event and school that a candidate went to. Knowing this, I should be able to pre-populate the dropdown list with the name of the school that the form is for instead of having the candidate choose. I want the name of the school to pre-populate as if it was already chosen before any clicks were made and I want the dropdown list to still be available just in case it needs changed.

You'll see in the code I've included that I have tried `{{getSchoolById(mylocalEvent.schoolId)}}` which actually works and returns the name of the school which the event corresponds to. However, when this is pasted in for `<mat-select [(value)] = 'mylocalEvent.schoolId'`, I receive an error instead of the expected pre-populated school.

```html
<td>
    {{ getSchoolById(mylocalEvent.schoolId) }}
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Schools</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="mylocalEvent.schoolId" required id="school" formControlName="school">
            <mat-option [value]="item.schoolId" id="schoolOptions" *ngFor="let item of schoolSource">
                {{ item.schoolName }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select><!-- End of mat-select -->
    </mat-form-field><!-- End of mat-form-field -->
</td><!-- End of td -->
```

I expect the dropdown to be pre-populated with the name of the school for it's corresponding event.

Comment: What kind of error do you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td>
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-label>Schools</mat-label>
                        <mat-select [(value)]='mylocalEvent.schoolId' required id='school'>
                            <mat-option [value]='item.schoolId' id='schoolOptions'
                                *ngFor="let item of schoolSource">
                                {{ item.schoolName }}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select> <!-- End of mat-select -->
                    </mat-form-field> <!-- End of mat-form-field -->
                </td> <!-- End of td -->
            </tr> <!-- End of tr -->
            <tr>
                <td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a reactive form, so don't use `[(value)]`, angular doesn't care about it, only cares about the form control. So set the value to the form control instead, either on initialization:

```ts
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  school: [this.mylocalEvent.schoolId],
});
```

and template should just have the form control name, not the value:

```ts
<mat-select formControlName="school">
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9k5qp-udxgse?file=app/input-overview-example.ts)**

or if you get the value later, use `this.myForm.get('school').setValue('value here!')`